# Django mock not getting called at all

Tags: django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I have test defined looking like below

```
    @patch('user.serializers.validate_sns_token', return_value=True)
    def test_can_create_user(self, validate):
        """
        Test that user can be created without logging in
        :return:
        """
        user_payload = self.generate_user_payload()

        resp = self.client.post(
            CREATE_USER_URL,
            user_payload,
        )

        self.assertTrue(validate.called)

        self.assertEqual(
            resp.status_code,
            status.HTTP_200_OK,
        )
```

Inside the user.serializers.py file I have below function that I would like to mock

```
def validate_sns_token(**kwargs):
    try:
        ...
        return True
    except ValueError as e:
        ...
        return False
```

It's an external call to google api so I would like to always return True from it.

Inside the serializer I am calling the create function like below

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...

        is_token_valid = validate_sns_token(
            sns_id=sns_id,
            sns_type=sns_type,
            token=token,
        )

        if is_token_valid is False:
            raise serializers.ValidationError('토큰이 유효하지 않습니다. 다시 로그인해주세요.', code='AUTH')

        ...

        return user
```

Unfortunately, the validate.called is always False and the original validate_sns_token is still getting called. How do I write a test so that the original validate_sns_token is not called at all but its return value is set to True?

Comment: I don't think you can pass `return_value` to a `patch` decorator. You need to pass it to a MagicMock and use that as `new` or pass is using `spec_set`.

Comment: @Exelian how do I turn it into MagicMock?